# Can you associate SSL certificates with Azure app service on Pay-as-you-go?

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate

I made an app service - deployed  and my final part of the puzzle is my SSL certificate. When I click on that option in Azure's portal (app service menu for my app) they are all greyed out with the words

> "App Service Environments are available in the Premium tier. They
>   offer even greater scale options, private access, and more.".

I'm on pay-as-you-go so I feel like I should be able to select the service I would like? When I click on upgrade - it just goes to my account page tries to upgrade to pay-as-you-go (even though I already have that) and then times out.

Failing that - does anyone know a way to get around this and letting me upload my ssl certificate? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need the App Service Environment to deploy custom SSL certificates (that's a good news, since ASE isnt cheap :)).

Since you want to upload your own SSL certificate, I assume you want to have your own domain (and you did configure it in the `Custom domains` blade already, otherwise you will not be able to assign certificate anyway), then all you need is B1 or higher pricing tier instance, where custom domains are available, more details about differences in pricing tiers can be found here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Note that for Microsoft managed domains (so ending with `azurewebsites.net`), MSFT is the owner of the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Azure Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-powershell-ssl-binding